# Is it possible to have a dependency on a JAR file in a NetBeans module project?

Tags: netbeans

I have created a NetBeans module project and need to add a dependency on a JAR file I have created- is this possible?  I only see the option to add a dependency on a nother module.  I am using NetBeans 6.5.1.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Modules can only depend on other modules.

Create Library that references your class, then create a "Library Wrapper Module" that encapsulates the library as a module.

Comment: Is this restriction really true? Maybe NetBeans has valid reasons for it, but I just can't believe it.

Comment: Keep in mind that these are modules within the NetBeans platform. Not JSR-277 modules. Thus, any jars the module needs, must also be installable within the NB platform.

Comment: In 6.9 this is already changed and you can have simple jars directly.