# How to simply add jar files, as libraries in a Netbeans module suite?

Tags: netbeans, module

I'm a bit confused with NetBeans (versions 6.5 and 6.7). I have a NetBeans Module Suite application, which consists of several NetBeans Modules. I need to add some code in one of the modules. The new code is using a library, distributed as several jar files.

The problem is, that NetBeans does not allow me to add this library jars directly to the classpath. It wants to wrap all the jars in a new Library Wrapper Module, which is then added to the project and used from there. The effect is that all the original jars are combined into a single new jar automatically by NetBeans. This is a problem, because I can't just replace the jars later, without rebuilding this "Library Wrapper Module" and the original library is updated nightly.

I read some NetBeans forums, but I found nothing... I tried with simple java application, where it is possible to simply add jar(s) to the classpath using Project Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder. If you use a NetBeans module instead of a simple application, the Libraries dialog looks different and does not have the "Add JAR/Folder" button.

Is it possible to add a plain normal jar in a NetBeans module and how?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099324/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dependency-on-a-jar-file-in-a-netbeans-module-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the way a user can wrap a jar has changed in NetBeans 6.8.

[image]

Since this has been integrated into a property dialog of a project, the build process might be smarter, too.  And it seems like that was your primary concern....

Comment: I'll accept this answer. Also in 6.9 I can simply add the jar as a library. No need to do this fancy "wrapping" anymore, which is good